# Single ant upload list item only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design to upload csv with this form input:

```
ce(Form.Item, { className: 'form_input' },
        ce(Upload, { onChange: handleFileChange, className:'csv', multiple: false },
          ce(Button, { type: 'ghost' },
            ce(Icon, { type: 'upload' }), ' Choose File',
          )
        ),
      )
```

The form allows multiple uploads and the new uploads get appended to "ant-upload-list-item". How can I prevent the append and only keep the latest item in there?

Answer (score 7):

**I tried with below code which worked fine for me for uploading single file and update uploaded file name.**

```
const props = {
    name: 'file',
    multiple: false,
    showUploadList: {
        showDownloadIcon: false,
    },
    onRemove: file => {
        this.setState(state => {
            return {
                fileList: []
            };
        });
    },
    beforeUpload: file => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            fileList: [file]
        }))
        return false;
    },
    fileList
}
```

Can work for both Upload and Dragger

```
<Dragger {...props} >
  <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
      <Icon type="cloud-upload" />
  </p>
  <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
</Dragger>

<Upload {...props} accept=".asc,.pem,.pub" style={{ width: '100%' }} tabIndex={3}>
    <Button disabled={is_view} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Icon type="upload" />
        {this.state.fileList && this.state.fileList[0] && this.state.fileList[0].name ? this.state.fileList[0].name : 'Click to Upload'} 
    </Button>
</Upload>
```

On Submit-

```
 const formData = new FormData()
 formData.append('file', this.state.fileList[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you probably want to show only the LAST file uploaded, though. so:
```this.state.fileList[this.state.fileList.length - 1]```

Answer (score 5):

The `multiple` prop you are specifying is concerning if we allow selecting multiple files in the file select popup, so it doesn't help you here.

There is no immediate way to show only the last upload, but using the `fileList` property you can implement your own display to accomplish that. See https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-fileList

Answer (score 4):

Use `maxCount` prop

```
<Upload
    listType="picture"
    accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
    maxCount={1}
>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
</Upload>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the maxCount property to 1. It will replace the previous upload with the new file.

You can check the documentation here -> https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-fileList